# CRUD operations with custom fields

Tags: users, entities, services

I am using Services 3.x with Drupal 7 and trying to expose a custom field added to the User object through the services. What is the easiest way to implement it for all operations (create, retrieve, update, delete)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the field has been created you will see the field on retrieve user resource (not index), and you will be able to send data on crud operations.